# save image directly to specified folder in ascending order of filename

Tags: java, opencv, jframe, save-image

Main thing is that I am fresher in JAVA. I got stuck with some code.
I want to save an image capture by a button directly in a specific folder. up to now I am using a file chooser to save my image
I want to save image in `C:\temp` and file name can be image,image1,image2 in ascending order

```
  int returnVal = jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this);
  if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)   
  {
       File file = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
       Highgui.imwrite(file.getPath(), frame);

  } else {

       System.out.println("file access cancelled by user.");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JAVA so someone may give you a more specific answer but all you need to do is add a counter onto your file path. The pseudocode algorithm would be this:

1. Initialise Counter = 0
2. Get file path - C:/temp
3. Get file name - Image
4. Append counter to file name - Image1
5. Add on image type - Image1.png
6. Append file path and name - C:/temp/Image1.png
7. counter++;

**Edit:**
Here is a simple System.Out example of how to build up a string:

```
 System.out.println("C:\Temp " + FileName + ".png" );
```